# Mocha test ignoring errors

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, chai

I'm trying to write a test, where a function is expected to throw an error.

```
it("function throws an expected error", function(done){
                return someAsyncError().then(function(){
                    expect(1).to.be.equal(1)
                })                      
            })
```

this test will alwys fail due to the error. how do I catch the error so the test will be true?
I dont want to use `expect(someAsyncError).to.throw()`

Comment: *this test will alwys fail due to the error* - what is the error? What is someAsyncError?

Comment: someAsyncError is a function that will throw an error. what kind of error doesnt matter for solving this problem.
my question is how to do a test with `expect` after this function has thrown an error (which is expected), maybe by using `catch`

Comment: The description is not enough. Please, provide error message and the code for someAsyncError. .catch is a likable solution, but it's impossible to say without seeing what's going on. Rejected promise isn't same thing as an exception, which could be tested with `to.throw`.

Answer (score 0):

Use NodeJS [asset.throws()](https://nodejs.org/api/assert.html#assert_assert_throws_block_error_message), so your code can be like:

```
 it("function throws an expected error", done => {
   assert.throws(someAsyncError, Error, "Error thrown")
 })
```

Comment: You don't need to add any external library, I'm just saying he can use the prebuilt function

Comment: i dont want to test if a functions throws an error, but rather test something after a function throws an error. but when using `.catch`, it will just ignore the `expect.` inside the catch block